# Article template and bibliography style for the journal "database"

Tags: templates

The Oxford journal "Database: The Journal of Biological Databases and Curation" usually prefers submissions as Word files :S but I already have a fully prepared article in LaTeX. It does not provide a template itself although many such templates exist for other Oxford journals. So I'm wondering if anyone has prepared a template for this journal before? I'm interested in both, an article template and a bibliography style file. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome, what does the journal editors want you to get them? A camera ready pdf, or the text to be further treated?

Comment: If it is the latter, don't bother. There are people getting paid to make your text apply to the journals specs, especially the bibliography-style.

Comment: That is a good point and unfortunately not entirely clear to me from the [help pages](http://www.oxfordjournals.org/our_journals/databa/for_authors/general.html). There are very clear rules regarding figures and references style but nothing regarding general layout. So I assume it will be edited further.

Comment: Well, to be honest, simplest way would be to drop the editor a quick question before investigating further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @johannes_B the journal "Database" accepts generic article layouts. Nevertheless, I have created a reference style that matches the [description](http://www.oxfordjournals.org/our_journals/databa/for_authors/general.html) as closely as I was able to. The `.dbj` file can be found in the [following gist](https://gist.github.com/Midnighter/a0bed44063f929b8792d). Simply run

```
latex database.dbj
```

on it in order to create the appropriate `.bst` file.